# jquery.flexslider: touch on thumbnail slider not working on iOS

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm using flex-slider's thumbnail controlnav for my slideshow. it works just fine on PC and Mac but on my iphone touching a thumbnail doesn't change the main slider's image. I haven't altered the jquery.flexslider.js file at all. The demo of the controlnav from the official site seems to work fine on my phone though. I don't have my own Mac so I cant debug with my phone directly :/. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Let me know if you need me to post html or any other code.

Here's what it should be doing:
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Here's what I have for my slider declaration:

```
 $('#carousel').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   controlNav: false,
   animationLoop: false,
   slideshow: false,
   itemWidth: 210,
   itemMargin: 5,
   asNavFor: '#slider'
  });


  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
$('#carousel').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   controlNav: false,
   animationLoop: false,
   slideshow: false,
   itemWidth: 150,
   itemMargin: 0,
   asNavFor: '#slider'  
 });
```

If I replace it with the demo code the touch works, but it also creates a bunch of extra empty boxes

```
 $(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: "thumbnails"
});
});
```

thanks!

Will

Comment: are you calling flexslider twice on the object?

Comment: can you post your code on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: You can use [Adobe Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/) to use Chrome's developer tools to debug a webpage on your iPhone if you have a Creative Cloud subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to flip the items - you're calling flexslider on `#carousel` twice but never on `#slider`. One is being synced, the other is the nav.

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
   asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
$('#slider').flexslider({
   sync: '#carousel'  
 });
```